# Replace while loop with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I was trying to find a way in lodash to do this:

```
var start = 0;
while (rows[start].substring(0, 1) === "#") {
  start++;
}
```

The actual code is skipping all the top lines until it doesn't find a # at the beginning. I was hoping there was a bit nicer lodash method that I could do something like

```
var start = _.someMethod(function (str) {
  return str.substring(0, 1) === "#"
})
```

So basically a lodash method to find the first index that does not match some query. Does that exist?

Comment: Note that your code as written will throw if all the lines start with #.

Comment: Totally, this is a simplified version, but thanks for pointing that out in case :)

Answer (score 6):

There's an aptly named [`_.findIndex()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findIndex).

```js
var rows = [ "#zero", "#one", "#two", "three", "#four" ];

var index = _.findIndex( rows, function (str) {
  return str.charAt(0) !== "#";
});

console.log( index );  // 3
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.12.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rows is an Array. You are looking for [_.findIndex](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findIndex)

Answer (score 0):

You can compose a specific function, something that lodash is very good at.

```js
var rows = ['#zero', '#one', '#two', 'three', '#four'];
var startsWithHash = _.ary(_.partialRight(_.startsWith, '#'), 1);
var notStartsWithHash = _.negate(startsWithHash);
var findIndexNotStartsWithHash = _.ary(_.partialRight(_.findIndex, notStartsWithHash), 1);
var index = findIndexNotStartsWithHash(rows);
console.log(index); // 3
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```